# CamelHttpResponseCode is null on service error

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm new to camel and writing a small POC to implement in an existing application. Application takes a xml request as input which contains the requested services and relevant data. It then calls those services one by one.
When a service is called successfully then I retrieve the http response code in a processor like below and do further logic:

```
Object code = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);
    if(null!=code && code instanceof Integer)
    {
        responseCode = (Integer) code;
    }
```

**In success case, responseCode received = 201**

Based on the responseCode, I know if the service call is successful and then proceed with the next one.

However, I tried to produce the negative scenario by making the service url incorrect and can't see the http response code anymore:

Original service url - `http://xxx:0000/.../.../.../.../...`

Modified service url - `http://xxx:0000/.../.../.../.../abc/...`

**In failure case, responseCode received = null**

In postman, I get the below error:

> org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP
>   operation failed invoking `http://xxx:0000/.../.../.../.../abc/...`
>   with statusCode: 404  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:274)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:183)

I don't know why exchange doesn't contain the http response code when it's present in the error message in the postman.

I'm using onException to handle any exceptions and then calling a processor to process the flow further:

```
<camel:onException>
                <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
                <camel:process ref="xxxProcessor" />
            </camel:onException>
```

I think I can consider responseCode=null as failure and proceed with my logic but want to understand why response code is being returned as null.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems that in case of service exception, an instance of org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException is thrown and the http status code is present in it. It can be retrieved in the processor like below:

```
Exception e = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
if(null!=e && e instanceof HttpOperationFailedException)
        {
            HttpOperationFailedException httpOperationFailedException = (HttpOperationFailedException)e;
            responseCode=httpOperationFailedException.getStatusCode();
        }
```

Comment: Upvoted and at the same time added an answer that made it work for me

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer helped me and it might have been valid! In the camel version I'm usin (2.20.1), getting the exception via the property does not seem to work. The following does

```
HttpOperationFailedException httpOperationFailedException  = exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
if(null!=e) {
    responseCode = httpOperationFailedException.getStatusCode());
}
```